# How do I copy output from a command in a Terminal window of VSCode so I can paste it elsewhere?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code to develop a Laravel project in Windows 10. I've opened a Terminal window and executed a command to create a new Laravel project. The output from the command identifies a number of errors. I want to copy the output from the command into a Stack Overflow post but when I try to copy from the Terminal output by dragging the cursor over the 30 or 40 lines of output, nothing gets copied into my buffer. What do I need to do to copy the output of the command of the terminal window so that I can paste it elsewhere?

Comment: Drag over the text, then try pressing `Ctrl+C` or if that doesn't work `Ctrl+Shift+C`

Comment: @Enderbyte09 - You rock!! I had tried Ctrl+C, which didn't work, but your suggestion of Ctrl+Shift+C worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag over the text you wish to copy in the Terminal tab, then hit `Ctrl+Shift+C` (or `Ctrl+C` if on Windows). Then, you can paste it with `Ctrl+V` normally.